# EF: TPH implementation with Fluent mapping throws Invalid Column Name exception

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface, table-per-hierarchy

Here is my implementation.

```
 public partial class Person
 {
    #region Constructors

    public Person()
    {            
        PersonExpirableCredentials = new List<personexpirablecredential>();
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    public int PersonID 
    { 
        get; 
        protected set; 
    }

    public virtual ICollection<personexpirablecredential> PersonExpirableCredentials
    {
        get;
        set;
    }        

    #endregion
}

public abstract class PersonCredential
{
    #region Constructors

    public PersonCredential()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int PersonID 
    { 
        get; 
        protected set; 
    }

    public int PersonCredentialID 
    { 
        get; 
        protected set; 
    }      

    public System.DateTime WhenEffective 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public Nullable<system.datetime> WhenExpire 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public virtual Person Person
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public partial class PersonExpirableCredential : PersonCredential
{
    #region Constructors

    public PersonExpirableCredential() :
        base()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public DateTime? WhenCompleted
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string CredentialNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Below are the fluent mappings

```
internal partial class PersonMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<person>
{
    #region Constructors

    public PersonMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.PersonID);       
        this.ToTable("Person");
    }

    #endregion
}

internal partial class PersonCredentialMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<personcredential>
{
    #region Constructors

    public PersonCredentialMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.PersonCredentialID }); 
        this.ToTable("PersonCredential");
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonID);          
    }

    #endregion
}

internal partial class PersonExpirableCredentialMapping :  EntityTypeConfiguration<personexpirablecredential>
{
    #region Constructors

    public PersonExpirableCredentialMapping()
    {
        this.Map(m =>
        {
           m.Requires("CredentialCategoryCode").HasValue("Expirable");
        });
        this.ToTable("PersonCredential");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the database model:

[image: TPH Diagram]

Now in my data access layer, when i retrieve the person and try to do access "Person.PersonExpirableCredentials". It throws an error with Invalid Column Name "Person_PersonID". Below is the SQL query, it generates.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
''1X0X'' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[PersonCredentialID] AS [PersonCredentialID], 
[Extent1].[WhenEffective] AS [WhenEffective], 
[Extent1].[WhenExpire] AS [WhenExpire],  
[Extent1].[WhenCompleted] AS [WhenCompleted], 
[Extent1].[CredentialNumber] AS [CredentialNumber], 
[Extent1].[Person_PersonID] AS [Person_PersonID]
FROM [dbo].[PersonCredential] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Person_PersonID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Person_PersonID] = @EntityKeyValue1) AND ([Extent1].[CredentialCategoryCode] = ''Expirable'')',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=3
```

For some reason, EF is not able to identify the relationship between the Person Class and the subclass PersonExpirableCredentials.

Help Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Person).WithMany(p => p.PersonExpirableCredentials).HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonID);
```

Modify your collection to be of base type

```
public virtual ICollection<PersonCredential> PersonExpirableCredentials
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same error. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Person_PersonID'.
Invalid column name 'Person_PersonID'.
Invalid column name 'Person_PersonID'.

Comment: That will return the base type which not going to work. There will be other collections of similar type in Person like public virtual ICollection<PersonCredential> PersonExperience {get; set;}

Answer (score 0):

You must set both getter and setter of the `PersonID` to public.

```
public int PersonID 
{ 
    get;
    set;
}
```

There are several places you have set the setter protected. Change those to public as well.